# Nonsensical result that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $(c_1z + c_2)^{-1}$ about the origin is infinite

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

For some reason I seem to get a nonsensical result for the radius of convergence of the following function: Let $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ and $f(z) = \frac{1}{c_1z + c_2}$. Then a quick computation shows that $f^{(n)}(z) = \frac{(-1)^nc_1^n}{(c_1z + c_2)^{n+1}}$ whenever $z\neq \frac{-c_2}{c_1}$. Hence $f(z;0) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{c_1^n}{c_2^{n+1}}z^n$ is the Taylor expansion of $f$ about the origin.

Now if $\left|z\right| < \left|\frac{c_2}{c_1}\right|$, $f$ is well-defined and the series converges absolutely and uniformly. But, the exact definition of the radius of convergence is

$$\rho \equiv \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup \left(|a_n|\right)^{1/n}\right)^{-1}$$

for the coefficients $a_n$ of a series. In our case $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{c_1^n}{c_2^{n+1}}$, so that

$$\left|a_n\right|^{1/n} = \left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{c_1^n}{c_2^{n+1}}\right|^{1/n}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\left|a_n\right|^{1/n} = \left|\frac{1}{n!}\right|^{1/n}\left|\frac{c_1}{c_2}\right|^{1/n}\left|\frac{1}{c_2}\right|^{1/n}$$

Then $\left|a_n\right|^{1/n}\to 0, n\to\infty$, for $\left(\frac{1}{n!}\right)^{1/n}\to 0$. Hence $\rho = \frac{1}{0} = \infty$. But clearly $f$ is not well-defined at $\frac{-c_2}{c_1}$. So what is going on with the radius?

Comment: The $n!$ in your Taylor expansion are wrong.

Comment: More precisely, when you differentiate $f$ you introduce a $n!$ from the successive derivatives so it cancels out leaving the Taylor coefficients as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Taylor expansion is incorrect.

$$
\frac{1}{c_1z+c_2} = \frac{1}{c_2} \frac{1}{1 - (- \frac{c_1z}{c_2}) } 
$$

This is the sum of a geometric series with initial term $\frac{1}{c_2}$ and ratio $-\frac{c_1z}{c_2}$.

So the Taylor expansion about $z=0$ is $\frac{1}{c_2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-\frac{c_1}{c_2})^k z^k$, and the sum converges when $|-\frac{c_1z}{c_2}|< 1 $, i.e. when $|z|< \frac{|c_2|}{|c_1|}$.

This also makes sense since the pole of $f$ is at $z = \frac{-c_2}{c_1}$, so this is the largest possible disk centered at $z=0$ on which $f$ is holomorphic.

I suggest getting really comfortable with geometric series in particular, since the proof of analyticity of holomorphic functions involves using Cauchy's integral formula to represent $f$, expanding the Cauchy kernel $\frac{1}{z - \zeta}$ in a geometric series about the base point $p$, and then integrating term by term.